# Typescript: mixin compilation error whilst complying with error

Tags: typescript, typescript-mixins

I wrote the following mixin class

```
export interface IFlyable {
    fly(): void;
}

export function Flyable<TBase extends ObjectConstructor>(Base: TBase) {
    return class extends Base implements IFlyable {
        constructor(...args: any[]) {
            super(...args);
        }

        public fly(): void {
            console.log('I am flying');
        }
    };
}
```

But my IDE underlines the `class` keyword with the following message

> A mixin class must have a constructor with a single rest parameter of type 'any[]'.ts(2545)

Besides that I am really really not a fan of it, I actually already supplied this constructor in my mixing class. It is the very first piece of code available

```
constructor(...args: any[]) {
  super(...args);
}
```

What exactly does the compiler or the language expect of me to resolve this error?
I must add that this error does not occur when I change the function declaration to this

```
export function Flyable<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase)
```

with `Constructor` defined as following

```
interface Constructor {
    new(...args: any[]): Object;
}
```

I am using Typescript v5.1.3 with the ES2022 specification in my tsconfig.json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hylq9.png)

Comment: `ObjectConstructor` is the type for the global object, `Object`. It isn't a type for a class constructor... So that leaves us in a weird spot. What would you want in an answer? https://tsplay.dev/m0vBGw